# How to load Bucketed HIVE table using LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH

Tags: apache-hive

Can we load a Bucketed HIVE table using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH ...` command. I have executed it for a sample file, but data values are inserted as NULL.

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ cat /home/hduser/Desktop/hive_external/hive_external/emp2.csv
    101,EName1,110.1
    102,EName2,120.1
    103,EName3,130.1

hive (default)> load data local inpath '/home/hduser/Desktop/hive_external/hive_external' overwrite into table emp_bucket;
Loading data to table default.emp_bucket
Table default.emp_bucket stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=0, totalSize=51, rawDataSize=0]
OK
Time taken: 1.437 seconds
hive (default)> select * from emp_bucket;
OK
emp_bucket.emp_id   emp_bucket.emp_name emp_bucket.emp_salary
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
Time taken: 0.354 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
hive (default)> show create table emp_bucket;
OK
createtab_stmt
CREATE TABLE `emp_bucket`(
  `emp_id` int, 
  `emp_name` string, 
  `emp_salary` float)
CLUSTERED BY ( 
  emp_id) 
INTO 3 BUCKETS
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hive/warehouse/emp_bucket'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='true', 
  'numFiles'='1', 
  'numRows'='0', 
  'rawDataSize'='0', 
  'totalSize'='51', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1457967994')
Time taken: 0.801 seconds, Fetched: 22 row(s)
```

But when INSERTED using insert command the data got INSERTED successfully.

```
hive (default)> select * from koushik.emp2;
OK
emp2.id emp2.name   emp2.salary
101 EName1  110.1
102 EName2  120.1
103 EName3  130.1
Time taken: 0.266 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
hive (default)> insert overwrite table emp_bucket select * from koushik.emp2;
Query ID = hduser_20160314080808_ae88f1c8-3db6-4a5c-99d2-e9a5312c597d
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 3
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1457951378402_0002, Tracking URL = http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1457951378402_0002/
Kill Command = /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1457951378402_0002
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 3
2016-03-14 08:09:33,203 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-03-14 08:09:48,243 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 3.24 sec
2016-03-14 08:09:59,130 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 33%, Cumulative CPU 6.39 sec
2016-03-14 08:10:02,382 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 67%, Cumulative CPU 8.8 sec
2016-03-14 08:10:03,442 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 11.03 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 11 seconds 30 msec
Ended Job = job_1457951378402_0002
Loading data to table default.emp_bucket
Table default.emp_bucket stats: [numFiles=3, numRows=3, totalSize=51, rawDataSize=48]
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1  Reduce: 3   Cumulative CPU: 11.03 sec   HDFS Read: 12596 HDFS Write: 273 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 11 seconds 30 msec
OK
emp2.id emp2.name   emp2.salary
Time taken: 103.027 seconds
hive (default)> select * from emp_bucket;
OK
emp_bucket.emp_id   emp_bucket.emp_name emp_bucket.emp_salary
102 EName2  120.1
103 EName3  130.1
101 EName1  110.1
Time taken: 0.08 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

Question is can't a HIVE bucketed table be loaded from a file?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to enable bucketing before loading a file in a bucketed table.
Use this to set bucketing attribute first and then load your file.

```
set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
```

*comment here if it doesn't work.*

Comment: Still same issue after setting "set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;" as well

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Hive does not support bucketing on external tables. Thus, instead of the `LOAD DATA INPATH` route, you apparently have to `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE ...`, *cf* [hadoop tutorial](http://hadooptutorial.info/bucketing-in-hive/#Inserting_data_Into_Bucketed_Tables).